# Find the original report of a linked report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ms-reports

How to find the original report of a linked report in SSRS. Could anyone let me know how to find the main report of a linked report in the report manager.

Comment: Kindly recomend you to go through this tour stackoverflow.com/tour to use all the power of this Q&A site! :)

Answer (score 4):

To find the original report open Report Manager (YourReportingServer/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx) in your browser and select **'Manage'** in the option menu of report.

[image]

There in properties you can see **'Link to'** field that's the main report and you can change it here.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tried this and am able to see this in my local report server but not able to see "Link To" in staging server.

Comment: @user3519008, how could you be sure that your report actually has linked report? Try to create the new linked report and check its properties to see that the Link to field should be there for such a report.

Comment: For linked report icon will be different as mentioned in below URL                 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155998.aspx                                 Below are properties that i can see for linked report.                                     Modified Date:  
Modified By:  
Creation Date:  
Created By:                                                                                                         Do i need any permissions to view full properties?

Comment: @user3519008, yeah, the icon is different. Can not reproduce the problem... I've got 'Link to' field

Answer (score 0):

You can also query in TSQL the list of linked reports.

```
SELECT 
     [Original_Report] = [prt].[Path]
    , [Linked_Report] = [rpt].[Path]
FROM
    [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog](NOLOCK) AS [rpt]
    LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog](NOLOCK) AS [prt] ON [prt].[ItemID] = [rpt].[LinkSourceID] 
WHERE
  1 = 1
  AND [rpt].[Type] IN(4);
```